# Powershell script to get top 100 users who have a value for houseIdentifier in the Attribute Editor in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to create a script to get top 100 users who have a value for houseIdentifier in the Attribute Editor in Active Directory but I have not been able to be successful so far. All the scripts that I run only display basic information about user.

Could you please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps if you show the code you have been using already. But I assume you're using [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser). That will only return a specific set of attributes unless you ask for more. You specify the attributes you need with the `-Properties` parameter.

For your query, it would look something like this:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(houseIdentifier=*)" -ResultSetSize 100 -Properties houseIdentifier
```

If there are other attributes you want to display, you can add them to the `-Properties` parameter as a comma-separated list.

Comment: This helps, thanks. :) And I shall add my script in the future as well, thanks for the suggestion.